# How to update value of an object from knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs to bind data to table, and I want to update object at user click. Here is my code

```
    var Books = [{Book:"Harry Potter",Author:"J.K rowling"},{Book:"5 Point Someone",Author:"Chetan Bhagat"},{Book:"I too had a love story",Author:"Ravinder Singh"}];

    var appViewModel = function() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Amit");
        this.Books = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.Books(Books);
        this.updateBook = function() {
            this.Book("Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban");
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);
```

But it get error: "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function". How can fix it ?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jVQY8/8/

Comment: yes it is not a function because it a plane json data . cheers

Comment: Sorry but I opted to delete my answer and vote to close your Q&A. It seems like you're looking for a coding service rather tan solving the issue. We require effort from you.

Comment: simply use this which should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/jVQY8/12/ . cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need the properties of each of your `Book` object to be an `observable` as well. Use the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin (that is now built-in) for that:

```
this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books);
```

Also, it's a bit misleading to see those `this` twice when each refers to a different object. The common approach is:

```
this.updateBook = function(book) {
    book.Book("Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban");
};
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVQY8/11/)

Comment: i am learning knockout js.i have one question what this function does `ko.mapping.fromJS()` ? Books variable has json stored. can't we declare Books observableArray and initialize same place like `this.Books = ko.observableArray([ko.mapping.fromJS(Books)]);` i tried this code but got error.

Comment: Since `Books` is already an array of objects, `ko.mapping.fromJS` will  transform it into an `observableArray` of those objects. So, with your line, you end up with `observableArray` that is containing another `observableArray`.

Comment: so can we try this this.Books = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(Books)) ? does this line work same way ?

Comment: @Thomas, You'd still get the same structure. Also, your first snippet was actually even more nested that I thought, that would actually created 2 nested arrays.