# Knockoutjs initialize observableArray with data

Tags: knockout.js

This way I was trying to initialize observableArray with data at the time declaration but giving error `TypeError: this.Book is not a function`

Here is jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jVQY8/11/

```
var Books = [{Book:"Harry Potter",Author:"J.K rowling"},{Book:"5 Point Someone",Author:"Chetan Bhagat"},{Book:"I too had a love story",Author:"Ravinder Singh"}];

var appViewModel = function() {
            this.firstName = ko.observable("Amit");
            this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);
            this.updateBook = function() {
                this.Book("Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban");
            }
        };
```

When I try to initialize observable array this way `this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);` throwing error `TypeError: this.Book is not a function`

But the moment I initialize observable array this way `this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books);` then it is working fine.

So anyone can tell me what is wrong this way initialization code `this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);`

Could someone please help me with the answer so I can understand what is the difference between these two approaches below.

1) `this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books);`

2) `this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);`

Tell me what happens internally when this line execute `this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books);`

And what happens internally when this line execute `this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books);`

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639030/how-to-update-value-of-an-object-from-knockoutjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this.Books = ko.observableArray(Books)`, the only thing that is observable is the array itself, so trying to set a property (like `Book`) as if it were an observable will naturally fail.

When using `this.Books = ko.mapping.fromJS(Books)` instead, each object in the array and each field is made into an observable, which is why `this.Book('New title')` works.

Comment: thanks for reply. what u said i partially understand but it will be good if u explain the same with small sample code. i do not understand and visualize this line u said **the only thing that is observable is the array itself**

Comment: when you create an observable array, the array itself is what's observable, i.e. knockout will only notify on changes to the array itself, not the members of the array. Adding or removing items to/from the array will notify, but updating a field on the nth item will not. What `mapping.fromJS` is doing is making each array member an object wherein each field is observable too. Read up on these pages: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html